# How to get a metric in results for all nodes?

Tags: omnet++, veins, inet

At the end of simulation, the metric results ( such as end-to-end delay) are shown for each node individually , so How can i get the mean value for all nodes or for a certain nodes.
I am using instant veins-4.7.1

Answer (score 1):

This is a generic statists question. Given several mean values, how do you calculate the mean of all values? Add all the measurements together and then dived by the total number of measurements. Statistics in OMNeT++ collect also the SUM_VALUE and number of measurements (COUNT) for each module, so you can calculate those values too, in your own post processing script.